# How to see new indexes when create script of table in Azure SQL?

Tags: indexing, azure-sql-database

I have database table on Azure SQL. It is system versioned table.
I see that Azure recommends indexing for table.

I have copied recommended script "CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX..."
And executed successfully Indexing commands.

I can see that performance got better.
I see new index if I list all indexes in Azure SQL database.

However I don't see new indexes if choose in SSMS "Table" and "Script Table as Create To".

Why I cannot see indexes related to the table?

Comment: Is "the table" the base table or the history table? Are you scripting the correct table in SSMS?

Comment: I do see Indexed folder if I open system versioned table in SSMS. I can do script indexes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SSMS by default, script indexes is set to False.

Change the settings to TRUE in SSMS under Tools menu-->options-->SQL server Object Explorer-->scripting-->`script indexes = TRUE`.

[image]